# Where can I ask questions for website recommendations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange site where I can ask others to recommend me good web sites for solving specific problems?

For example I would like to know if there is any URL shortening website that can allow me to define the url.

For example instead of `http://bit.ly/1gX2dD0` I would like it to be `http://bit.ly/superflow` - if "superflow" is not available then I will invent another word.

I can imagine that such services are paid but I don't need the link to last more than one day, and maybe there is such a website.

Comment: Bitly already allows you to do that...... for free.... you just need to create an account.

Comment: If you're asking for a recommendation for a web **application**, those are acceptable at [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0):

There is no such Stack Exchange site for website recommendations. Back in 2015, there was an Area 51 proposal, but it did not have enough popularity, and was eventually rejected as a result.

While other sites may appear to cover the *subject* of website you are asking about, recommendations are very much opinion based. As such, it is quite likely that such questions would be *closed* as *primarily opinion based*. If you want absolute clarification, you should check with that site's specific meta.